# Cursor position at EOF and BOF

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Where is the Position of cursor in recordset.EOF and recordset.BOF.  Any explanation or link info is appreciated much.

Comment: Do you know what EOF and BOF mean?

Comment: Have you opened the VBE window, typed EOF or BOF in the Immediate Window and hit the F1 key top open the Help on EOF/BOF? The explanation seems quite clear. Suggestion: check the Help file before you post a question on SO, and if you still don't understand, then tell us what in the Help file is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ref:

- [Recordset::EOF](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/recordset_eof.html)
- [Recordset::BOF](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/recordset_bof.html)

Comment: @Pronek
You may visualize the BOF and EOF positions as follows: If you have a recordset with n rows (starting in row 1, of course), BOF can be understood as position 0, and EOF as position n+1. As the recordset doesn't really have 0 or n+1 rows, BOF and EOF are simply flags: BOF means that there are not any rows before the current position, and EOF means that there are not any rows after the current position.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering why, for example, a loop has not exited with movenext when you hit the last record, it is not yet EOF, movenext again and you will hit EOF. The same, of course, applies for the other direction and BOF.